# Sum the products of numbers in range <a, b> that digits are prime number

Tags: java, math

I have got a little problem—I need to prepare program that (step by step information):
1)Gets from user two integers `a` and `b`  and stop when `b`>`a`
2)Sum the products off all numbers in range < `a`, `b` > that digits are prime numbers
Example:
Input: 10, 15,
Output: 2340
 (because 12*13*15 = 2340
 **2, 3 and 5 are prime numbers**)

I feel like I stuck—I have got only a sum of the numbers (not the product) and not the prime but all of them.

```
public class Ex4 {
    static int getNmbs() {
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    public static int getSum(int a, int b) {
        if (a > b)
            return 0;
        else
            return a + getSum(a + 1, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = getNmbs();
        int b = getNmbs();
        int c =getSum(a,b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 is not a prime number. 2 is a prime, but you seem to have skipped it for some reason ...?

Comment: are you multiplying or adding your primes? You're doing it differently in your description and in your code

Comment: I'm not sure why your `getSum` method does what it does. Does your exercise specify that it's not allowed to just use a for loop? Use a for loop to go through the numbers and in each step, use a method that checks if the number is the kind of number that you want. If it is, you are supposed to update the result by multiplying with that number.

Comment: Sorry-my brain fizzled out. I just fixed it.

Comment: Now your question is unclear. If prime numbers are 2,3,5, why are numbers that start with the digit `1` included? Should only accept numbers like 23, 55, 72, etc., which are not in your range.

Comment: First, as stated, 1 is not a prime.  So that would seem to exclude 12, 13, and 15 since they each include a non-prime.  And where do you check if a digit is either 2,3,5, or 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, you need to think of the step by step process:
First, accept two integer inputs, **a** and **b**.

Declare a variable to hold your product (the answer) and initialize it at 1. (If you initialize it at 0, then you will always get 0)

Now, assuming **a < b**, check to see if the digits of **a** are prime. IF it is, multiply your product by it and increment **a**. If it isn't, just increment **a**.

Rinse and repeat until **a > b**. And return the final product.

The trick here is going to be figuring out a way to check if the digits of a number are prime. I suggest using modulo division in increments of powers of 10 (for those more mathematically inclined) or converting the integer to a String and checking each character (using toCharArray).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a non recursive approach.

```
 static boolean isProductPrime(int num){
    int tmp         = num % 10;   
    if( tmp < 2)    return false;

    for(int i = 2; i*i <= tmp; i++) //Instead of Math.SQRT
        if(tmp % i == 0)   return false; 

    return true;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = myScanner.nextInt();
    int b = myScanner.nextInt();

    int ans = 1;
    for(int i = a ; i <= b ; i++){
        if(isProductPrime(i))
            ans *=i;
    }
    if( b < a) 
        ans = 0;
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```